# Symfony2: is the Type constraint useful in combination with Doctrine ORM column type definition?

Tags: validation, doctrine-orm, symfony

Quick question:
When you define, in your ORM column definition, that a column is of type string, for example. Is it of any use to also define a constraint that says that the type needs to be string?
Even more: is it a best practice to do so? Or is it just double work for nothing?

I would assume it is the first, since in this case you can catch the problem during validation, rather then during flushing. I think :-)

Example code:

```
/**
 * @var string $type
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Type(type="string")
 */
private $type;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with the constraint a bit, I'm pretty sure I answered my own question :-)

> I would assume it is the first, since in this case you can catch the
>   problem during validation, rather then during flushing. I think :-)

So, yeah. There we go ^^ If anyone disagrees, please speak up!

Comment: When you -1 this, can you please have the common decency to say why?

Answer (score 1):

I think the column type is for the schema (eg: for when you do doctrine:schema:update), and the assert type is for the validation (eg: $validator->validate($user)).

Comment: Indeed it is :) But either way, the data won't get through, even if you don't put the Type constraint on it. But I'm pretty sure that it's useful actually, since it takes care of it during validation, which should be quite a bit before flushing, and easier to catch :)